# Ignore case-sensitive in search javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have something like this:

Html

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" onkeyup="searchFunction()" style="width:300px;" />
```

Javscript

```
    function searchFunction() {
    $(".contact-name") /*Contact-name is the name of the div*/
    .hide()
    .filter(":contains('" + $("input[name='keyword']").val() + "')")
    .show();
    }
```

So it works, but when the div contains text something like george and i type GEORGE in the search textbox, it doesnt work, so can you help me?

Comment: You can convert them to lower case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Answer (score 0):

[`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) accepts a function, so I'd probably use that and do a case-insensitive comparison:

```
function searchFunction() {
    var find = $("input[name='keyword']").val().toLowerCase();
    $(".contact-name") /*Contact-name is the name of the div*/
    .hide()
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(find) != -1;
    })
    .show();
}
```

I'd also be tempted not to hide them all up front and then reveal the matches, but rather to update each of them individually:

```
function searchFunction() {
    var find = $("input[name='keyword']").val().toLowerCase();
    $(".contact-name") /*Contact-name is the name of the div*/
    .each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggle($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(find) != -1);
    });
}
```